# cubic number in the form $ 9k+b $

Tags: number-theory

how could i prove that a cubic number $ u^3 $  is always of the form $ 9k+n $ where $n=0,1,2,3,4,\ldots,8$

can a similar proof be made to prove that a power of n $ n^k $ is of the form

$ am+b$ where k,m,a,b,u and n are integers $a=a(m) $ and $ b=0,1,2,3,\ldots,a-1 $

what congruence should i solve ? apparently i should study the congruence

$ u^3=b \pmod 9$ but i have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: What about $27 = 3^3$?

Comment: $ 27=9*3 $ yes i forgot the case $n=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Every* integer has form $\rm\: 9\,q+r\:$ with remainder $\rm\:0\le r< 9\:$ by the division algorithm.

Less trivially, one may show that cubes are either $\,0\,$ or $\,\pm1\!\pmod 9$.

$\rm {\bf Hint}\ \ \ mod\ 9\!:\ (j + 3k)^3 =\, j^3\! + 9(\cdots)\,\equiv\, j^3\in \{0,1,2\}^3 \equiv \{0,1,-1\}$